# Unknown link showing in GTMetrix water flow due to some js code

Tags: java, html

I have ripped a page made in clickfunnels to host on my hosting for better page load time. There is a link diplaying in GTMetrix waterfall which is due to some JS code. I am unable to find this code calling this tracking event. my web page link is http://alleytohealth.com/top/dreamcar/

The links displaying in water fall are

http://track.addevent.com/atc/?trktyp=jsinit&trkcal=&guid=73cc96d0-f775-4ea9-fd88-e80550099250&url=http%3A%2F%2Falleytohealth.com%2Ftop%2Fdreamcar%2F&cache=1556407181664

and

https://track.addevent.com/atc/?trktyp=jsinit&trkcal=&guid=73cc96d0-f775-4ea9-fd88-e80550099250&url=http%3A%2F%2Falleytohealth.com%2Ftop%2Fdreamcar%2F&cache=1556407181664.

I haven't placed any tracking code of custom JS while creating this page in clickfunnels.

I have checked the js files in my assets but nothing found.

js code for this page is very long. here is the link for only js file i have on my server http://alleytohealth.com/top/dreamcar/lander.js

i don't want my page to call these two links.